# Discrete colour scales using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, scale

I am trying to create a map in ggplot but are having trouble with colour scales.
I want to create a colour scale with breaks corresponding to 0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 and >0.4, with colours ranging from blue, green, yellow, orange to red where everything >0.4 is red.

```
scale_fill_gradientn(breaks=c(0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4),
                       minor_breaks = NULL,
                       guide = "legend",
                       colours = mycolours,
                       limits = c(0, 0.4))
```

My issue is that "limits = c(0, 0.4)" restricts the colour allocation, where data >0.4 is grey but without it everything is in the lower range (blue).

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the limits to something slightly greater than 4, like `c(1, 4.1)`? You could also look into `scale_color_brewer`, it has easy gradient options: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_brewer.html. You could try specifying what the `low` and `high` color values:  http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-colors-how-to-change-colors-automatically-and-manually#continuous-colors ; or